# Is this a good imagination of $f$ (4.1 Remark; Rduin)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

[image]

I'm trying to understand how to construct $f$; is the following sketch right (not drawn to scale)?

[image]

$2^{nd}$ question: Does every dense subset of $R$ have no isolated point and how to prove it?

Comment: To the second question (which should have been posted seperately): Yes. Proof: write down an (appropriate) definition of dense set, write down an (appropriate) definition of isolated point. See that these definitions *directly* contradict each other.

Comment: @M.Winter I just wanted to see the reason why $E$ must be dense. It turns out that if $E$ is dense and $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $E$, then the discontinuities of $f$ aren't isolated.

Comment: The correctness of your sketch depends on what $E$ is. It seems in your case $E=\Bbb N$. I do not see what you mean by "$E$ must be dense". The text says "may even be dense". If $E$ is dense, there are no isolated discontinuities.